# Modify stage appearance

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way of modifying the appearance of the "floor" of the field in certain regions without adding obstacles?  I'm making a simulation where bee-like robots congregate under areas of high temperature, and I want to show these regions of high temperature by coloring the floor of the field in those regions differently than the rest (so there will be big red circles in some spots and the rest will be the normal checkerboard pattern).  Is this an option, or do I have to configure my own visualization window or something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61441/modify-stage-appearance/) by [katniss](https://answers.ros.org/users/4664/katniss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-04-29**:
do you want to visualize the temperature regions on stage or rviz? or it does not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently stageros support certains capabilities of stage simulator,(like just laser ranger sensor and just allow one laser per robot), if you want to add extra features, like a background, (I want this too), you have to make a custom simulator based on stage (maybe modifying stageros?).

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not just add objects to the world file that are "short", and make sure that the object has the following properties `obstacle_return 0` and `blob_return 1` (would be visible and look right from cameras and the GUI, but not something that would cause a collision with the robot.)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-29**:
This answer assumes that you're using the camera sensors so the robot (and the person using the GUI) could detect the special regions of the floor.